# Delayed Jobs workers getting timed out on engineyard

Tags: delayed-job, engineyard

I think i'm having a problem where engineyard is adding a timeout to some of my delayed job workers, (seems to be 10 minutes).  I have a copy process that can run for > 10 minutes and everytime it gets to that 10 minutes threshold the job is killed.  Is there anyway to configure the engineyard timeout for worker instances??  I'm looking through and all I see is timeouts regarding nginx/apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a timeout set for the Delayed Job workers, so this is more likely a memory usage issue. Monit tracks the memory consumed by the workers and will restart those that reach a set threshold. Monit's actions will be logged in `/var/log/syslog`, so this can be checked to confirm if Monit is terminating the workers. The memory threshold is set in the `/etc/monit.d/delayed_job.monitrc` file(s) and can be increased to fit the workers' requirements. After alteration of the configuration Monit must be reloaded using `sudo monit reload`.

If you submit a ticket at https://support.cloud.engineyard.com the support staff will be more than happy to help you further diagnose this issue.

Comment: I came here to answer my own post, but you were right.  It ended up being monit killing it after it got to a memory threshold, which just happened to be at about 10 minutes everytime.  I increased the threshhold and it's working correctly.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll note that we had our dj-monit configured through a chef recipe, not directly through the server itself per-se.  Re-configuring the recipes and re-uploading them fixed our problem via:

ey recipes upload -e environment
ey recipes apply -e environment